# Wake On Lan not working (Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS)

Tags: networking, server, wakeonlan

I've been trying to get WoL working on my Ubuntu Server, but have had no luck.

Steps taken so far:

1. Enabled WoL as directed by the mobo manufacturer in my BIOS and later disabled fast boot (just in an attempt to try everything.
2. Ensured that the device is able to enable WoL with `sudo ethtool enp0s31f6`
3. Enabled WoL on `enp0s31f6`.
4. Created a script to ensure that `wake-on: g` on startup.
5. Set `wakeonlan: true` in netplan.

And I've tried to send the Magic Packet through multiple methods. That is, through 2 different WoL programs on my PC (WakeOnLan and WakeMeOnLan), and through my Raspberry Pi with the wakeonlan package.

Not really sure what to try next.

(The server in question):

```
CPU: I5 7600
Motherboard: ASUS H110m-a/m.2
Memory: 8GB DDR4 2133mhz
Storage: WD Blue SN570 500GB
```